# How to count the number of distinct polynomials formed from these factors?

Tags: combinatorics, field-theory

This is more of a counting question than anything. I have $x, x - 1, x - 2$ in $Z_3[x].$ How do I count the number of degree 3 polynomials these factors can form? So obviously it isn't $3^3$ because these factors commute. So how do I account for overcounting? I can obviously list them out and cross out the repeated ones, but is there a closed form formula that allows be to count something like this?

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{F}_3[X]$ is a UFD.